# Can I set a bounty to a on hold question?

Tags: discussion

Can I set a bounty on one of my questions that is put on hold ? Here is the [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64117/drive-by-download-attacks-what-can-cause-the-file-to-be-downloaded-without-inte). I do not see where to click to set a bounty for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The fact that it is on hold means it is not available for answering, so a bounty would make no sense.

That specific question has been closed as it is unclear what you are asking - I would suggest editing accordingly so that it can be reopened, and then you can place a bounty.

You have been given a lot of guidance on how to do this in the comments on that question.

Comment: adding -> asking